# 3d tracking vertical video not working

Tags: camera, tracking

For some reason I cannot 3d track footage in blender that is shot vertically (1080x1920). I had an idea to rotate the video to landscape (1920x1080) and see what happens. Sure enough, it tracks perfectly. Without even trying I got a solve error around 0.24. I replicated these settings and applied them back to the video in portrait mode and it doesn't work. I did see a post here from last year, but it didn't really help. Why would tracking the video vertically cause so much trouble? Is it a limitation?

Thanks
[image]